# mysql 5.5 to 5.7 migration issue with geometry object getting error 1416

Tags: mysql

i am planning to upgrade my server from Ubuntu 12.04 to Ubuntu 16.04, as i was trying in my PC the migration to check if everything will work as expected. I am facing issue with MySql table which has geometrical columns like polygon

MySQL Ubuntu 12.04 server version is 5.5.43 and 
MySQL Ubuntu 16.04 server version is 5.7.12

I did mysqldump with and without --hex-blob , i get the my table exported with binary data, which i tried to insert to my new MySQL server with 5.7.12 gives me the below error

**error 1416 (22003) at line 1901: Cannot get geometry object from data you send to the GEOMETRY field**

the mysqldump version i am using in Ubuntu 12.04 is 
mysqldump  Ver 10.13 Distrib 5.5.43, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64)

can anyone help me how can i export from mysql 5.5 to mysql 5.7 the tables with geometry object

thanks for your support

Comment: did any one have these issues and got it resolved ?